# Opening Visual Studio .dbp projects in MonoDevelop

Tags: monodevelop, database-project

Is there a way to open a Visual Studio 2008 database project (.dbp) in MonoDevelop? The project is in SVN, and needs to remain compatible with Visual Studio, because I'm not the only programmer who works on it.

Is there an add-in or something for this that I'm missing/not aware of, or am I just going to have to stick with Visual Studio for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of one, and I'm one of the core MD developers. If you're interested in contributing such an addin, head over to our [mailing list](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/monodevelop-list) and we can give you some pointers on getting started.

Answer (score 0):

[Prebuild](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnpb/) might be an alternate solution :

> Prebuild is a cross-platform
>   XML-driven pre-build tool which allows
>   developers to easily generate project
>   files for major IDE's and .NET
>   development tools including: Visual
>   Studio .NET 2002, 2003, 2005,
>   SharpDevelop, MonoDevelop, NAnt and
>   Autotools

Basically, you can generate almost all IDE project files from a specific prebuild XML build file. This XML file could be stored in your SVN repository and people can use the IDE they want.

Comment: Prebuild doesn't support MD's database projects, and it's inferior to MD's native MSBuild project/solution support.